# Fetch a long json from an API

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, fetch, velo

I have a Google Cloud function that I use as an API to retrieve some data with a fetch call.

- My website is hosted on wix.
- I use WIX nodejs environnement (VELO) as my back end.

When I use my function on the frontEnd of wix, it works and retrieves the long BASE64 sequence required (800ko) as a string, displayed in console.

When I use it in the backend, it does not work.

```
export async function toCode(imgURL, sequenceToTranslate) {

const api_url = "MY_API_URL";
// const key = await getSecret("QRAPIKey");

var myHeaders = {};
myHeaders["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
myHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer MY_KEY";

var raw = JSON.stringify({ "text": sequenceToTranslate, "width": 1500, "height": 1500});

var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: raw
};

return fetch(api_url, requestOptions)
    .then((httpResponse) =>{
        if (!httpResponse.ok) { return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");}
            console.log(httpResponse);// <== **Display in both front or back end**
            return httpResponse.json();
        })
    .catch((z) => { console.log(z); return z })

}
```

httpResponse.json() **works on the frontend, but is not processed when used on the backend.**

The reason for it not working is the **SIZE** of the DATA that is in the response from *my* API.
When I make sure that the base64 response is half the size : it works in the back end and I get the data as a console input.

(For the sake of readability I simplified the body of the request.)

**Is there a way to actually fetch a long piece of data retrieved from my API in the backend, without using buffer or stream?**

I have no idea if it is specific to wix or if it is something i must do on my end.

Comment: on the backend what package is `fetch`?

Comment: Right now I am using 'wix-fetch', but I get the same result if I use 'node-fetch'. @AlanOmar

Comment: The `JSON.parse(someString)` used inside of `response.json()`, as you have identified, does have a size limitation. You'll want to use `await response.text()` and then follow it up a call to a library designed to handle large JSON files such as [`bfj`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj). However with a file that large, you could just pass the `response.body` (a stream) straight into `bfj`.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into it

Comment: @AlanOmar It is a good answer use Big-Friendly JSON , could you please add your comment as an answer to upvote?